# Convert a SpeechSynthesisUtterance to audio blob

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

Using the javascript Speech Synthesis API, you can make the browser speak some text:

```
var message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('foo bar');
speechSynthesis.speak(message);
```

However I would like to do something other than speak the produced audio.

Is it possible to convert a SpeechSynthesisUtterance to an audio blob somehow?